# One Xcode project, Two targets, Two apps, Two Default.png files?

Tags: iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - multiple targets multiple launch images nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056794/iphone-multiple-targets-multiple-launch-images-nightmare)

I'm working on an iPhone app that will ship with a "Lite" and "Pro" version.  To accomplish this I'm using two targets with the same project and codebase.  I would like to use a different "loading" `Default.png` image for the two versions of the app, but I'm not sure how to do this short of manually overwriting the file before building each target.  Is there some way this could be automatically done during the build process?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://github.com/brennanMKE/MultipleTargets

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out - easiest solution is to create two separate directories, one "lite" and one "pro", and put a Default.png in each directory.  Import "pro" to only the "pro" target, and import "lite" only to the "lite" target.

Comment: Alternatively, one can forgo the directories altogether. Simply add both copies of Default.png to your project, right click on each image, select "Show File Inspector", and make sure (on the right pane) that the correct target is checked under Target Membership. This was all it took for me (running Xcode 4.4.1)

Answer (score 3):

For one of the targets you could change the build  phase so it loads a different `Default.png` file.  Go to the target's `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase to change what resources it copies. (Located in the `Groups & Files` pane under `Targets ->` *TargetName* `-> Copy Bundle Resources`)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This pane is a bit confusing to me- is there a way to actually rename the files or pull them from different places?

Comment: Well, by adding different Default.png files to different target's resources you can use different files.  I don't believe you can rename them because the file has to be called that... but you could reorganize them in their own resource folders in top area of the pane.