# iPhone - multiple targets multiple launch images nightmare

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a project with 2 applications in two flavors each, iPhone and iPad. So, the project has 4 targets. It is obviously not universal.

To easy things, lets call each application AAA and BBB.

The launch images are named like this:

**AAA for iPhone**

- AAAiPhone.png
- AAAiPhone@2x.png

**AAA for iPad**

- AAAiPad-Portrait@2x.png
- AAAiPad-Portrait.png
- AAAiPad-Landscape@2x.png
- AAAiPad-Landscape.png

The BBB images have the same name structure, with BBB instead of AAA in the name.

I have added this UILaunchImageFile to each plist, like this:

- AAA for iPhone ... Launch Image (iPhone) = AAAiPhone.png
- AAA for iPad ... Launch Image (iPad) = AAAiPad.png
- BBB for iPhone ... Launch Image (iPhone) = BBBiPhone.png
- BBB for iPad ... Launch Image (iPad) = BBBiPad.png

When I drag the images to the proper place holder on Xcode it goes fine for AAA, but when I do that for BBB it overwrites all AAA images. It appears to be ignoring the info.plist information.

Any clues?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because the images are renamed to Default.png (or another name same for each target).

You need to do it like this:

Add a entry in your plist for each target.
iPad: Launch image (iPad)
iPhone Launch image (iPhone)

[image]

Use a different string for each target.
Place the images with that string to your resource files (also make sure that only the desired images are active in the desired target).

**Example**:

- Target 1

  - plist: Launch image (iPad) = AAADefaultiPad
  - Place files: AAADefaultiPad@2x.png and AAADefaultiPad.png
- Target 2

  - plist: Launch image (iPad) = BBBDefaultiPhone
  - Place files: AAADefaultiPhone@2x.png and BBBDefaultiPhone.png

**Edit 1:**
Place the images as you would place a image file into your graphic resources. Do not place it in the image space under Target "Summary".

Works for me pretty well.

Comment: Don't drop the images into the image space under "Summary". Place it as a file in the resources! Then it must work. :)

Comment: Ok thanks, but it seems just to work if I add an entry called "Launch image" and is not working when the entry is "Launch image (ipad)". Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've written up instructions along with a GitHub project.

https://github.com/brennanMKE/MultipleTargets

There are many steps and details to handle for everything you will want to do to fully support multiple target builds from a single Xcode project. That sample addresses...

1. Unique app identifier for each build target
2. Unique launch graphics
3. Unique app icons
4. Custom C Flags to manage distinct functionality for each build target

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems regarding multiple targets(iPhone) X multiple launch images/multiple icons when I had to add Retina icons & launch images. To solve this, I had to do do the following in plist:

- Regarding Icons(low res & retina): In each target, I deleted the entry Icon Files (iOS 5), and added another one (Icon file). Then I modified this row (Icon file) to Icon files (basically, in singular it's type is String, and plural it automatically becomes Array), and added the image files reference, as the following:

[image: info.plist - Icons]

- Regarding the launch images (low res & retina): I did as Jonas suggested, but using the image with retina specs (640 x 960). It works both in low res and hi res.

[image: info.plist - Launch Image with hi-res png file]

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple:

1. Define "Launch image" in plist with a string you want to replace "Default" in the file name. Default.png becomes MyAppName.png etc.
2. Simply create your filenames conforming with default filenames such as:

MyAppName.png

MyAppName@2x.png

MyAppName-568h@2x.png

MyAppName-Landscape@2x~ipad.png

MyAppName-Landscape~ipad.png

MyAppName-Portrait@2x~ipad.png

MyAppName-Portrait~ipad.png

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I wasted two hours on these images. WTF Apple?